# Changing Font Size and leaving space between button in a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, joptionpane

The text in my JOptionPanes are way to small I was wondering how I could change the font of the text inside the pane.  Also, I would like to be set a space between two buttons.

Something like

```
   |Canecl|               |DoneSave| |Save|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean the fonts on your `JButton`s inside the `JOptionPane` are too small.

For that I suggest using [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) by Darryl Burke. Now you can easily do e.g.

```
for (JButton button : SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JButton.class, pane)) {
    button.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 32));
}
```

to set the fonts on all `JButton`s inside of `JOptionPane` pane.

If you want to set the font of the `JOptionPane` message itself, use e.g.

```
UIManager.put(
    "OptionPane.messageFont",
    new FontUIResource(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 32))
);
```

In regard to the "spacing of buttons" question: I don't know if that can be done without extending & make a customized `JOptionPane` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a spacing between just 2 buttons out of 3 (as per the OP's question) but you can increase the size of the spacing between ALL the buttons :

```
JPanel buttonPanel                     = (JPanel) myOptionPane.getComponent(1);   
BasicOptionPaneUI.ButtonAreaLayout lm2 = (BasicOptionPaneUI.ButtonAreaLayout) buttonPanel.getLayout();
lm2.setPadding(20);
lm2.setSyncAllWidths(false);     // buttons will vary in size as needed.
```

or perhaps something like :

```
lm2.setPadding(lm2.getPadding() * 2)  // double the spacing between ALL buttons.
```

If there were just 2 buttons, then using these **LayoutManager** calls you could achieve the desired outcome.

However for varying-sized spaces between the buttons you need to implement your own JDialog where you control the layout of its JPanel yourself.

A JOptionPane is made up of 2 JPanels... one for the message (and icon) itself, and one for the buttons, that's why we getComponent(1) above.

I know the question is 4 years old but I made this answer because I had a similar need today and couldn't find the answer ANYWHERE on Stack overflow or elsewhere.